# partial view error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have moved following code from my view to partial view and getting error

My view code is:

function renderSeason() {       

            $('#visSeasonbut').click(function() { $('#p2').load(this.href); return false; });
        }

        function renderGame() {          
                      $('#visGamebut').click(function() { $('#p2').load(this.href); return false; });       
        }

```
                         <div id="game">                            
                           <%= Html.ActionLink("Game 1", "PitcherTitles", "Test", null, new { id = "visGamebut" })%>   </div>
```

LiveGame.Models.Baseball.Player visPlayer1 = ViewData.Model.GetCurrentTeamPlayer(false);
                                             if (visPlayer1 != null)
                                             {
                                                 LiveGame.Models.Baseball.Player rosterPlayer = ViewData.Model.GetTeam(0).RosterDictProp.GetPlayer(visPlayer1.Player_IdProp);

```
                                             if (ViewData.Model.InningHalfProp == true)
                                             { %>

                                            show Pitcher Stats here
                                      <%


                                             }
                                             else
                                             { 
                                      %>
                                     Show PitchTitles here                                            


                                    <% 
                                             }
                                             }
```

and partial views are like this :

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

Wins
                                                Losses
                                                ERA

second one is :

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

IP
        
        
            H
        
        
            R
        
        
            ER
        
        
            BB
        
        
            SO
        
        
            HR
        
        
            ERA

When I click links, I get error , "rosterPlayer" not found, Please suggest solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code in action method?

Comment: public ActionResult PitcherStats() {
            Game currentGame = new Game();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PitchTitles() {
            Game currentGame = new Game();
            return View();
        }

Comment: **please** don't paste code in a comment - it is illegible. Instead, update your question. Also, since you're not returning a model in your `return View()` statements, your view doesn't have a model to work with - it's null, like the error says.

Comment: Tips & tricks: use `<%: %>` instead of `<%= Html.Encode(...) %>` (assuming You are working with asp.net mvc version 2).

Comment: Now I am working with MVC version 1

Answer (score 1):

When you render this partial make sure you are passing a model:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SomePartialName", Model); %>
```

And of course don't forget to strongly type your partial to the model:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.SomeModelType>" 
%>
```

Also from the comment you posted it looks like you aren't passing any model to your views. So change this and ensure a model is passed or you cannot use the Model property:

```
public ActionResult PitcherStats() 
{ 
    Game currentGame = new Game(); 
    return View(currentGame); 
} 

public ActionResult PitchTitles() 
{ 
    Game currentGame = new Game(); 
    return View(currentGame); 
}
```

Comment: I am rendering with jquery like this :    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="renderSeason();" >Season 1</a> 
                              <a id="visGamebut" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="renderGame();">Game 1</a>      and javascript code is : <script type="text/javascript">
        function renderSeason() {
              $.get("/Test/PitcherStats", null, function(data) { $("#p2").html(data); });
        }

        function renderGame() {          
           
            $.get("/Test/PitchTitles", null, function(data) { $("#p2").html(data); });         
        }
    </script>

Comment: @asif, OK, then pass a model when returning a view in the `PitcherStats` and `PitchTitles` actions.

Comment: How to pass it in my case ? in hrefs or in javascript functions or in action methods ?

Comment: Also, Can I do same thing without jquery?

Comment: What same thing? You didn't explain what is your scenario and what you are trying to do. All you said in your question is that you moved some code from your view to a partial. Obviously this information is not sufficient.

Comment: I have two hrefs which call jquery functions to render partial views. href1 clicked shows /Test/PitcherStats href2 clicked shows /Test/PitchTitles. Can I get rid of jquery and render partial views on click of hrefs using asp.net/ MVC code only ?

Comment: @asif, no, if you want to update only some regions of the page instead of reloading the entire page you need AJAX. If you want to reload the entire page you could use the `Html.RenderPartial` helper as I showed in my answer which will allow you to include the partial at some specific location of the page.

Comment: Any better code/link example of using ajax for partial view loading on hrefs click ?

Comment: @asif, the following should work fine: `$('#idofyourlink').click(function() { $('#resultdiv').load(this.href); return false; });`

Comment: @Drain : and how the href will look like ? do I need to put action path in href ?

Comment: @asif, yes, it could look like this: `<%= Html.ActionLink("Season 1", "PitcherStats", "Test", null, new { id = "idofyourlink" }) %>`

Comment: Hi Darin: Now I start getting error in partial view, Can I have your email address to show you code ?

Comment: @asif, update your question and post the relevant information. What error you are getting, etc...

Comment: Hi Drain: My view html is large and I am getting limit error. How to attach my view and partial view files ?

Comment: @asif, don't post large code snippets. Try to narrow down your problem to a simple code snippet you could show. Nobody has the time to read entire projects here. And by narrowing down the problem you probably will find the answer yourself. I mean learn how to debug your application: start a new project and put the strict minimum and see when it blows. This will allow you to isolate it.

Comment: Hi Darin: I have updated the question and posted only related code. Can you please check now ?